# How would one go with creating a "flying debris" effect with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, effects

I am working on some animation and am using the jQuery library.

One of the assets' method is `fly()`, which means to fly away from the parent element had that parent just *exploded*. It should look like flying debris, i.e. it should fly up and away and then succumb to gravity and fall. [Example](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=OSWk_9-VJIs#t=6s).

Here is my method so far...

```
var parent = this.element.parent(),
    direction = this.element.position().left < parent.width() / 2 ? '-' : '+';

this.element.animate({
    left: direction + '=300',
    top: '-=200'
}, duration);
```

This obviously doesn't look at all like flying debris, as it just moves up and away. The `direction` variable determines which way the element should fly. Because each element is relatively positioned to its parent, elements on the left hand side move to the left and vice versa.

I'd don't want to implement a full fledged physics engine such as Box2D.

I know what my code should essentially do, which I believe is...

1. Fly the elment up (negative `top`) and in the direction set (negative or positive `left`), with some value decaying to simulate loss of horizontal movement due to wind resistance etc and loss of vertical movement due to gravity.
2. The force of gravity will have grown stronger at some stage than the upward force of the element from the explosion, in which case the element will need to *fall*.

I don't really know how to approach this problem. I was hoping I could leverage jQuery's [`animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/), but I don't know to incorporate a *decaying* value.

What would be the best way to create this effect?

Comment: Do you just need a debris animation for eye candy, or does it have to be precisely calculated? I found that using random values can actually make it realistic. http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/fSaGk/

Comment: @minitech: Eye candy only. I'll see if I can fiddle with that fiddle to work in my project. Thanks.

Comment: @minitech That's one cool fiddle, I'll say!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(I will post this as an answer since that’s what it actually is.)

Do you just need a debris animation for eye candy, or does it have to be precisely calculated? I found that using random values can actually make it realistic. See http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/fSaGk

Comment: I just looked at this.  Very cool for large 'firework' like explosion!

Answer (score 1):

You're probably going to need to use the `easing` property of the `animate()` call, and leverage the [jQuery Easing Plugin](http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/) to get an effect somewhat more subtle than the standard `linear` easing offered by default in jQuery.

The other trick is to **chain** the calls to `animate()` to get that multiple-stage effect you're after.

Here's a *really* (and I mean *really*) quick [mockup](http://jsfiddle.net/7ATwk/) that kinda- sorta gives you an idea.

The guts of it:

```
debris.animate({
    left: direction + '=150',
    easing: 'linear',
}, {
    queue: false,
    duration: duration
})
.animate({
    top: '-=100',
    easing: 'easeOutQuint',
}, {
    queue: true,
    duration: vduration
})
.animate({
    top: '+=100',
    easing: 'easeInQuint',
}, {
    queue: true,
    duration: vduration
});
```

The key elements are:

- The left-right animation is `linear` - this is not the decay you're looking for but it's sufficient for this mockup
- The left-right animation is explicitly **not queued**, so the next `animate()` in the chain starts immediately
- The up-down animation consists of two **queued** (it's the default but I've specified it anyway for clarity) animations, each timed at half of the left-right animation
- I've used the `easeOutQuint` easing function from the Easing Plugin to do the gravitational effect - it's nowhere near perfect but you get the idea

With sufficient queueing and chaining of `animate()` calls like this you should be able to get a pretty nice decaying *x* together with a good-looking gravity-inspired *y*...

Answer (score 0):

I ended up modifying [minitech](https://stackoverflow.com/users/707111/minitech)'s code extensively...

```
var element = $('div'),
    parent = element.parent(),
    position = element.position(),
    offset = element.offset(),
    directionOver180 = false,
    flyAnimation;

$('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');

var angle = (Math.random() * 180) + (directionOver180 ? 180 : 0),
    angleCalc = angle * Math.PI / 180,
    velocityX = Math.cos(angleCalc),
    velocityY = Math.sin(angleCalc),
    currentX = offset.left,
    currentY = offset.top,
    gravity = -20;

flyAnimation = setInterval(function() {

    currentX += velocityX * 5 * (directionOver180 ? -1 : 1);
    currentY += velocityY * 3 + ++gravity;

    velocityX += 0.02;
    velocityY += 0.1 * Math.random();

    element.css({
        left: currentX,
        top: currentY
    });

    if (currentY + element.height() > $(window).height()) {
        $('body').css('overflow', 'visible');
        clearInterval(flyAnimation);
        element.remove();
    }

}, 20);
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/5mDu7/).